# Asynchronous Loop Process inside a aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

we are implementing an asp web application with .net4.0.
we want to make an async loop to do something and will only end if the page is unloaded or closed.

is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Does the `window.setInterval` work for you? It repeats the same method on and on from time to time. (It's on the client-side)

Comment: have not tried it yet, however if possible, we would like to implement this server-side

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a PageAsyncTask.

Details can be found on implementation at the msdn website:

[Page.RegisterAsyncTask Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: it blocks the page_load events

Comment: What do you mean it blocks the page_load events?